# python pandas parse_dates np.array vs list

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, csv

OK, so I'm quite lost about the following piece. I have .csv files that I would like to be parsing into dataframes with Pandas. Some of the columns in the .csv should contain dates, and so I'd like to attack them with the `parse_dates` flag in the `pd.read_csv`. So I go about this the following way that I first define my 'schema dataframe' indicating the data types that I expect in the file for their respective columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_schema = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1), 
    data={'dtype_expected':[
                np.dtype('datetime64[ns]'),
                np.dtype('datetime64[ns]'),
                np.dtype('datetime64[ns]'),
                np.dtype('float64'),
                np.dtype('datetime64[ns]')
                ]
        }
)
```

And then 'compute' the columns' indices that I would like to parse as dates:

```
parse_dates = df_schema[
                df_schema['dtype_expected'] == np.dtype('datetime64[ns]')
              ].index.values
```

So this results in `type(parse_dates)` being a `numpy.ndarray` (`array([0, 1, 2, 4], dtype=int64)` in the case above), and since I know `pd.read_csv` will expect a list of integers for the `parse_dates` I wrap it with the `list()` constructor in the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    file_path, 
    error_bad_lines=True, 
    sep = ';',
    decimal=',',
    parse_dates=list(parse_dates)
)
```

But his crashes with a `KeyError: 0`.

(!!!) **Interestingly**, if I type in the code `parse_dates = [0,1,2,4]` (i.e., I don't compute it but simply put in the values), then the snippet above works like a charm! Very confused about this one. Also, this demonstrates that the problem is not related to the data.

Comment: I've run into this error before and didn't come to a completely satisfactory solution. I found that there was a record that would not coerce to a date. The way I got around it was to import the csv as a regular file then use `df['my_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['my_date'],errors = 'coerce')` then just looking manually at the dates that returned N/A. Fortunately, it was easy to fill those in my dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why but the changing the snippets above into:

```
parse_dates = df_schema[
                df_schema['dtype_expected'] == np.dtype('datetime64[ns]')
              ].index.tolist()
```

rather than `values`, and then:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    file_path, 
    error_bad_lines=True, 
    sep = ';',
    decimal=',',
    parse_dates=parse_dates
)
```

solves it. Can't really say why there would be a difference between `list(index.values)` (the original code) and `index.tolist()` (the changed code) but apparently there is some.